# jQuery - visibility query in if statement does not work

Tags: jquery, html

My check for visibility does not work. What is wrong?
I forgot to add the jquery library, sorry. But in my project there is a jquery lib, what could be wrong?

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/npgnuhum/3/)

HTML

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

JS

```
if($('.box').is(':visible')) alert("box is visible");
```

Comment: you forgot to add jquery in fiddle its working see here http://jsfiddle.net/npgnuhum/5/

Comment: It is working, you have not added jquery library from dropdown on the left. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/npgnuhum/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code is alright, its not working because you missed out adding jQuery library

```
if ($('.box').is(':visible')) alert("box is visible");
```

[Check Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/npgnuhum/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Check it out.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/npgnuhum/8/)

```
if ( $(".box").is(":visible") ) {

    alert("box is visible"); }
```